# grep cares about .dat extension?

Tags: grep

GNU grep 2.6.3
Linux version 2.6.32-220.el6.i686 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)

I have a .dat file that grep will not function on.  It's plain text and can be read by all standard output commands, e.g. "less", "cat", etc, so I know what it contains.

If I grep a phrase I absolutely know is in there it does not return, as if it found nothing.

The oddity is if I simply rename it with a different extension, like `file.dat.txt`, now grep will work just fine.  If I rename it back to `file.dat`, once again grep will not find anything.

I also created a .dat file simply with the echo command:
`echo "grep this" > test.dat`
And still, `grep "grep" test.dat` returned nothing.
But after `mv test.dat test.dat.txt`, now `grep "grep" test.dat.txt` worked just fine.

Easy enough workaround (rename the file) but just thought this was odd behavior.

Comment: What is the output of `command -v grep`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not normal behavior and I cannot reproduce the issue on my ubuntu nor centos machines.

It is very likely that `GREP_OPTIONS` is set in your bashrc (or bash_profile, profile or so on) to ignore *.dat.

To verify this, simply print the env variable:

```
 echo $GREP_OPTIONS
```

Somewhere in the output you should see `-exclude=*.dat`

EDIT: As suggested by Fox in the comments it could also be an alias, then `command -v grep` should show `-exclude=*.dat` somewhere in its output

Comment: Could be an `--include` set as well, suggest mentioning that.

Comment: From the documentation, on `GREP_OPTIONS`: "As this causes problems when writing portable scripts, this feature will be removed in a future release of grep, _and grep warns if it is used_" (emphasis added)

Comment: @Fox that warning isn't mentioned in the grep 2.5.1 docs, and 2.5.1 does not warn. Remember OP is running a *very* old grep.

Comment: I stand corrected: OP is using 2.6.3, which also mentions no warning

Comment: Oh boy, I feel silly.  Thank you, yes, it was GREP_OPTIONS.